# App Store and iTunes API: Getting icon

Tags: api, app-store, itunes

I am using request like this:

```
http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsLookup?country=ru&id=
```

It shows information about the app from the Apple App Store but I have some problems with icons.

If i'm getting property **artworkUrl60** it is too small 60x60 image, but it is rounder.
And with **artworkUrl100** I'm geting 512x512 image that is too big, not rounded and looks ugly when I'm sizing it down to 100x100.

How can I can get nice looking rounded 100x100 image?

Answer (score 25):

You must get `artworkUrl512` and then replace ".png" or ".jpg" with specific size ".100x100-75.png" or ".100x100-75.jpg"

See also list all available image formats (png / jpg):

- 42x42-50
- 53x53-50
- 60x60-50
- 72x72-65
- 75x75-65
- 29x29-75
- 53x53-75
- 58x58-75
- 64x64-75
- 84x84-75
- 100x100-75
- 114x114-75
- 128x128-75
- 150x150-75
- 170x170-75
- 175x175-75
- 200x200-75
- 256x256-75
- 340x340-75
- 350x350-75
- 512x512-75

Comment: Hi Nika, great find! Could you post a link to where you found these dimensions?

Comment: @epologee this link not exists.

Comment: Could you then tell a bit about how you got to this? Was it brute force? Did you piece it together from Apple docs somewhere? Is it 'complete' or do you think there are more variations? Cheers.

Comment: Good find. Wonder if this is documented anywhere.

Comment: This seems to be partly broken recently. Some image urls end with `?downloadKey=234234324... ` i.e. maybe http://host/somefile.png?downloadKey=3elkdjlkdjfsdlkfsldf For me, the ones ending with "downloadKey=XXX" can NOT be transformed using the ".150x150-75.png" method described above. I have not tried other sizes.

Comment: Also, even some image urls that do not have "?downloadKey=xxx" just won't work with this method. An official API reference would help!

Comment: New question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666002/itunes-api-artwork512url-method-of-getting-different-icon-sizes-no-longer-work

Answer (score 3):

`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1036264023`

As per documentation in iTunes Search API : 
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery and add the `ui-corner-all` class to images to make them have rounded corners. This works for any size image.